# create a second row for a list in python and write list to txt file

Tags: python, list, io, row

I have a code which at a stage has the following line:

```
n_brace.extend([numEL, valueLX[j],valueB[jj], el[2]])
```

This line is included in a for loop so it produces for example:

```
n_brace:
[367, '62', '141', '142', 369, '124', '156', '155', 379, '344', '266', '265', 381, '313', '251', '252']
```

However I want it to be instead:

```
n_brace:
[[367, '62', '141', '142'], [369, '124', '156', '155'], [379, '344', '266', '265'], [381, '313', '251', '252']]
```

At the end of the program I open a file and want to write `n_brace` to it:

```
fbrace = open("C:/Abaqus_JOBS/brace.txt", 'w')
fbrace.write(n_brace)
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
367, 62, 141, 142
369, 124, 156, 155
379, 344, 266, 265
381, 313, 251, 252
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `extend()` to `append()`:

```
n_brace.append([numEL, valueLX[j],valueB[jj], el[2]])
```

As for the writing (assuming Python 2.x):

```
with open("C:/Abaqus_JOBS/brace.txt", 'w') as fbrace:
    for row in n_brace:
        print >>fbrace, ', '.join(map(str, row))
```

Comment: I get: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int32 found`

Comment: the text I get written in the file is not the one from n_brace is something else: `[1 1 2], [2 2 3], [3 3 4], [4 4 5], ....`

Comment: @jpcgandre: Now *that* I very much doubt. Make sure you haven't overwritten `n_brace` somewhere in your code.

Comment: If I replace by `join(map(str, n_brace))` I get: `[367, '62', '141', '142'], [369, '124', '156', '155'], [379, '344', '266', '265'], [381, '313', '251', '252']
[367, '62', '141', '142'], [369, '124', '156', '155'], [379, '344', '266', '265'], [381, '313', '251', '252']
[367, '62', '141', '142'], [369, '124', '156', '155'], [379, '344', '266', '265'], [381, '313', '251', '252']
[367, '62', '141', '142'], [369, '124', '156', '155'], [379, '344', '266', '265'], [381, '313', '251', '252']` I get four equal lines and the  [ and ' symbols.

Comment: @jpcgandre: Is that `nbrace` or `n_brace`? To the interpreter, those are two different names.